Framer Motion - Orchestrate the start of children's sequence animations with a parent wrapper
I have children with complex 'sequence' animations. I would like to orchestrate each child's sequence to start when the previous one's is over. (please note, I cannot handle the children's animations with variants)
Currently, I've 'solved' this by manually passing a delay to each Child element's sequence.
<div>
<Child delay={1}/>
<Child delay={2}/>
...
</div>


My Child is set up like this.
useEffect(() => {
animate( 'MY SEQUENCE', delay)
},[])

My question is I would like to orchestrate the delay of children that use sequence animations, with a parent element rather than delay 'controls' on each one. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance!
As above. The animation is working as desired but it's not 'orchestrated' correctly.
